# OnPageChangeListener makes ViewPager laggy

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm having a problem with a ViewPager being laggy ONLY on some devices ONLY when i use the onPageSelected method of an OnPageChangeListener.

This is the listener:

```
public class SelectorChangeListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i2) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int i) {
        onLineSelected(mAdapter.getLinePalina(i));
    }
}
```

This is the onLineSelected method:

```
/**
 * Called when a line becomes selected
 * @param linePalina LinePalina Object
 */
public void onLineSelected(LinePalina linePalina) {
    if(D) Log.d(TAG, "Called: onLineSelected([linePalina])");
    Palina palina = linePalina.palina;
    Line line = linePalina.line;
    mHeaderText.setText(palina.getName());
}
```

Inside the adapter this is the getLinePalina(int) method:

```
public LinesSelectorFragment.LinePalina getLinePalina(int position) {
    return mLines.get(position);
}
```

mLines is a simple ArrayList of LinePalina objects.

What could be the cause of this lags that disappears when i disable the OnPageChangeListener ?

**EDIT**:
I tried to remove ANY lines from the OnPageChangeListener, so now it's empty, it's being added to the ViewPager like this:

```
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SelectorChangeListener());
```

And **Even with an empty listener* the ViewPager is laggy on some devices (Galaxy Tab 2 7.0) While if i comment out that line:

```
//pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SelectorChangeListener());
```

The viewpager works perfectly!!! HOW is this possible?

Comment: Hard to tell from what you describe.  Have you tried profiling in DDMS?  A couple things come to mind to check: how much work is going on in getLinePalina()?  How much work is happening for setText() - it probably engages the spell checker, which is quite time consuming.

Comment: stupid question, maybe, is the pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new SelectorChangeListener()); in the onCreate/onResume method? You can also add some logs in the methods of the listener to see if they are invoked too many times...

Answer (score 0):

That is a really weird bug. I was having the exact same situation on General Mobile Discovery device with Android 4.2.1. It was working perfectly on other devices such as Samsung Galaxy S3, Nexus 5 etc.

Then, while debugging I saw that the `onPageScrolled` was being called a lot of times. In fact, it was being called infinite times if user keeps his finger on the screen and keeps swiping without leaving his finger from the screen. I was changing text of my TextView inside `onPageScrolled` method and since that method is called a lot of times, it was causing very laggy behavior. I managed to solve the problem like this:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    int lastScrolledPagePosition = 0;
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        if(position != lastScrolledPagePosition) {
            txtImageCount.setText(position + 1 + "/" + imageUrls.size());
            lastScrolledPagePosition = position;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
});
```

Hope this helps someone having the same problem.